# MPI_Wtime() confusion - does not appear correct

Tags: mpi, benchmarking

I'm using MPI_Wtime() to measure the speed of a parallel application.

Running the application on 4 cores completes in 0.000061 (takes around 30 seconds)

Running on 50 cores, 0.000308. (instantaneous)

Multiplying the workload 10x, still on 50 cores, the time is 0.000752. (around a 2 minutes irl)

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ofstream file;
    file.open("primes.txt");
    file.close();

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0)
        t1 = MPI_Wtime();

    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0)
        Parent parent(size);
    else
        Child child(size, rank);

    if (rank == 0) {
        t2 = MPI_Wtime();
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    if (rank == 0) 
        printf("Runtime = %f\n", t2 - t1);

}
```

Parent contains a loop to manage children.

These numbers do not make any sense. What am I doing wrong?

MPI_Wtick() is 1e-9

Comment: What do you mean by "takes around 30 seconds" ? What takes 30 seconds? The usual way to time an application is to put barriers before and after, and timing calls immediately after the barriers. That way you know that you time the whole applciation and not just the parent.

Comment: did you define `t1` and `t2` as double? if they are global variables, what if you declare them as local variable? you can also print `t1` right after it is set, and print it again at the end to make sure it was not overwritten as the consequence of a memory error such as a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Giles Gouaillardet and @Victor Eijkhout for answering.

After moving t1 and t2 to be local and adding `MPI_Barrier` before each recording of the time, I was able to get an answer that made sense.

Running the code on 4 cores gave a result of 20.277840, which sounds correct.

Before, this same test gave a result of 0.000061, which does not make any sense at all.

Thank you.